# Rufus not running

Tags: system-installation

I used [Rufus 2.12](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) from W10 2 times, to install both CentOS and Ubuntu.

But now I want to install another OS, and Rufus does not work: it is displayed in tasks, but does not appear on the screen. What is the problem?

I think the problem is in Windows 10, but I do not know what exactly.
UNetbootin running, but it doesn't work to write CentOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to kill the process from the task manager , then reopen it as an administrator it should work, otherwise try the portable version .

You can also try another program like : [this one](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/home)

Comment: I'm an admin, and I confirm my action. I restarted Rufus, but it was the same. And yes, portable version is running now (although both of same size). Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you out, good luck :)